# Retrieve objects by container in LDAP

Tags: ldap-query

Does anyone know if it is possible in an LDAP query to filter objects according to the container they are in?

For example, I would like to return all users in the OU called staff, maybe something like this:

```
(& (objectCategory=user) (containerOU=Staff))
```

Obviously I just made up the containerOU bit, I'm just trying to illustrate what I mean.

At the moment, the only way I could do this is the bring back the entire Staff OU and iterate through it. I'm a SQL man, I'm used to being able to specify exactly what I want.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

You could search by the objects distinguishedName.

(distinguishedName=*OU=Staff, DC = blabla, DC = com)